# Compare 2 JSON objects and find best time JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am trying to figure out how to find the best time from 2 JSON objects based on the user key from the JSON object and build the correct array to display blocks with the best results.

First JSON object:

```
[
{
        "user1": "00:31.889",
        "user2": "00:32.739",
        "user3": "01:00.515",
        "user4": "00:28.336",
        "user5": "00:35.745"
    },
    {
        "user1": "00:26.470",
        "user2": "00:30.063",
        "user3": "00:28.696",
        "user4": "00:30.248",
        "user5": "00:35.123"
    },
    {
        "user1": "00:26.956",
        "user2": "00:33.588",
        "user3": "00:30.021",
        "user4": "00:29.154",
        "user5": "00:38.492"
    },
    {
        "user1": "00:27.190",
        "user2": "00:32.307",
        "user3": "00:30.467",
        "user4": "00:30.189",
        "user5": "00:39.669"
    },
    {
        "user1": "00:27.368",
        "user2": "00:28.124",
        "user3": "00:29.960",
        "user4": "00:29.649",
        "user5": "00:42.450"
    }
]
```

Second object:

```
[
    {
        "key": "user1",
        "label": "Alex"
    },
    {
        "key": "user2",
        "label": "Jane"
    },
    {
        "key": "user3",
        "label": "Frank"
    },
    {
        "key": "user4",
        "label": "Merlyn"
    },
    {
        "key": "user5",
        "label": "Josh"
    }
]
```

Return should be something like this: `[{name: 'Alex', value: 233433}]`

Have tried many options including Object.key but still cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Know my goodness

```js
const results = [
    {
        "user1": "00:31.889",
        "user2": "00:32.739",
        "user3": "01:00.515",
        "user4": "00:28.336",
        "user5": "00:35.745"
    },
    {
        "user1": "00:26.470",
        "user2": "00:30.063",
        "user3": "00:28.696",
        "user4": "00:30.248",
        "user5": "00:35.123"
    },
    {
        "user1": "00:26.956",
        "user2": "00:33.588",
        "user3": "00:30.021",
        "user4": "00:29.154",
        "user5": "00:38.492"
    },
    {
        "user1": "00:27.190",
        "user2": "00:32.307",
        "user3": "00:30.467",
        "user4": "00:30.189",
        "user5": "00:39.669"
    },
    {
        "user1": "00:27.368",
        "user2": "00:28.124",
        "user3": "00:29.960",
        "user4": "00:29.649",
        "user5": "00:42.450"
    }
]

const users = [
    {
        "key": "user1",
        "label": "Alex"
    },
    {
        "key": "user2",
        "label": "Jane"
    },
    {
        "key": "user3",
        "label": "Frank"
    },
    {
        "key": "user4",
        "label": "Merlyn"
    },
    {
        "key": "user5",
        "label": "Josh"
    }
]

const stringToObject = (str) => {
  const m = +str.split(":")[0];
  const s = +str.split(":")[1].split(".")[0];
  const ms = +str.split(":")[1].split(".")[1];
  return {m, s, ms}
}

const stringToMs = (str) => {
  const {m, s, ms} = stringToObject(str)
  return( m * 60 * 1000) + (s * 1000) + ms;
}

const getBestResults = () =>{
  const output = []
  for(let user of users){
     let min = Infinity;
     for(let result of results){
        const time = stringToMs(result[user["key"]])
        min = Math.min(time, min)
     }
     output.push({name: user["label"], value: min})
  }
  return output;
}

console.log(getBestResults())
```

[solution JsBin](https://jsbin.com/tasuhoqudi/edit?html,js,console)

this O(n^) but probly you don't care.

Answer (score 0):

#### A step-by-step solution

I think you can do this in two lines of Javascript.

Observe that you only need to know the lowest time of the entire list of times, and then give the identity of that person.

#### Line 1. Find the userId and time of the shortest time

- Convert each 5-element object into an array, so that the first 5 times are stored as one array: [ ["user 1", "00:31.889"], ["user 2", ...] ], and the next 5 are in another array etc. A good way to do this is to `.map` the original big array with the function `Object.entries`.
- Flatten the 5 different arrays you will have, in to a single long array. This will contain 5 times for user 1, 5 for user 2, etc. The Javascript `.flat()` function will do this for you.
- Get the userId-and-time pair with the shortest time. Since the times are all strings containing numerical values in the same format, with leading zeros, you can sort them alphabetically and take element #0 of the resulting list. A convenient way to do that is using the Javascript `.sort()` function. You want to tell the sort program to look at the [1]th element of each miniature array, which is the time, and not the [0]th element which will be the user Id (such as "user 1").

The code for that sequence of steps is:

```
times.map(Object.entries).flat().sort((a,b)=>a[1].localeCompare(b[1]))[0]
```

#### Line 2. Get the user name for that winning user

- From the list of users, you want to select out the one who has the same Id as the winning user. You can use the Javascript `.filter` function for this. The winning user's Id is winning[0], i.e. the first of the two items in the id-and-time pair. Get the filter function to test each user's Id against this.
- Javascript will give you a list, with one item in it. You want that first item, i.e. [0].
- Display that person's name (`.label`), and the winning time (`winning[1]`).

The code for this is:

```
users.filter(user=>user.key===winning[0]) [0] .label,winning[1]
```

I have not tried to convert the minutes and seconds into seconds, as I am sure you know how to do that, and your example correct answer seems to not match the data above. Presumably you are simply showing the type of information required, not specifying a conversion.

The code below should do what you need. Let me know if anything needs explaining more.

```js
const times = [{
    "user1": "00:31.889",
    "user2": "00:32.739",
    "user3": "01:00.515",
    "user4": "00:28.336",
    "user5": "00:35.745"
  },
  {
    "user1": "00:26.470",
    "user2": "00:30.063",
    "user3": "00:28.696",
    "user4": "00:30.248",
    "user5": "00:35.123"
  },
  {
    "user1": "00:26.956",
    "user2": "00:33.588",
    "user3": "00:30.021",
    "user4": "00:29.154",
    "user5": "00:38.492"
  },
  {
    "user1": "00:27.190",
    "user2": "00:32.307",
    "user3": "00:30.467",
    "user4": "00:30.189",
    "user5": "00:39.669"
  },
  {
    "user1": "00:27.368",
    "user2": "00:28.124",
    "user3": "00:29.960",
    "user4": "00:29.649",
    "user5": "00:42.450"
  }
];

const users = [{
    "key": "user1",
    "label": "Alex"
  },
  {
    "key": "user2",
    "label": "Jane"
  },
  {
    "key": "user3",
    "label": "Frank"
  },
  {
    "key": "user4",
    "label": "Merlyn"
  },
  {
    "key": "user5",
    "label": "Josh"
  }
];

// Line 1. Get the lowest time across all users and all attempts
const winning = times.map(Object.entries).flat().sort((a,b)=>a[1].localeCompare(b[1]))[0]

// Line 2. Display their identity and time
console.log(users.filter(user=>user.key===winning[0])[0].label,winning[1])
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation, now its more clear.
How can I output the best result for each user?
I was trying to remove the index at the end of the winner to output a full list of users but keep getting undefied.

Answer (score 0):

#### If you want the best score for each user, you need a different strategy

My earlier answer was on the basis that you wanted the time for the winner of the entire contest, not the best time for each runner.

My solution is to sort all the userIds-and-times in order of time. Then in that array, "user1"s best time is the first time in that ordered list that "user1" appears.

```js
const times = [{
    "user1": "00:31.889",
    "user2": "00:32.739",
    "user3": "01:00.515",
    "user4": "00:28.336",
    "user5": "00:35.745"
  },
  {
    "user1": "00:26.470",
    "user2": "00:30.063",
    "user3": "00:28.696",
    "user4": "00:30.248",
    "user5": "00:35.123"
  },
  {
    "user1": "00:26.956",
    "user2": "00:33.588",
    "user3": "00:30.021",
    "user4": "00:29.154",
    "user5": "00:38.492"
  },
  {
    "user1": "00:27.190",
    "user2": "00:32.307",
    "user3": "00:30.467",
    "user4": "00:30.189",
    "user5": "00:39.669"
  },
  {
    "user1": "00:27.368",
    "user2": "00:28.124",
    "user3": "00:29.960",
    "user4": "00:29.649",
    "user5": "00:42.450"
  }
];

const users = [{
    "key": "user1",
    "label": "Alex"
  },
  {
    "key": "user2",
    "label": "Jane"
  },
  {
    "key": "user3",
    "label": "Frank"
  },
  {
    "key": "user4",
    "label": "Merlyn"
  },
  {
    "key": "user5",
    "label": "Josh"
  }
];

// Line 1. Sort the user-and-time data into order of time, shortest first.

const orderedTimes = times.map(Object.entries).flat().sort((a,b)=>a[1].localeCompare(b[1]))

// Line 2. Loop over each user, using "users.map", and for each user, filter ONLY the user-and-time elements that feature THAT user. Of that list of user-and-time elements, only take the first one, i.e. [0]. That will be that user's best time.

const usersKeyAndBestTime = users.map(user=>orderedTimes.filter(userKeyAndTime=>userKeyAndTime[0]===user.key)[0]
);

// Line 3. Output the result, replacing the user key ("user1") with their actual name.

console.log(
    usersKeyAndBestTime.map(
        keyAndBestTime=>[
            users.filter(
                user=>user.key===keyAndBestTime[0]
             )[0].label,
             keyAndBestTime[1]
         ]
    )
)
```